# Lists and ICollections

Tags: c#, inheritance, list, interface

Looking at the interface **System.Collections.Generic.ICollection** its definition requires that the inheriting member contains the property **bool IsReadOnly { get; }**.

However I then took a look at the class **System.Collections.Generic.List** which inherits  **System.Collections.Generic.ICollection** and this class does not contain a definition of **bool IsReadOnly { get; }**. How is the inheritance chain broken or  am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member is implemented explicitly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346454.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `IsReadOnly`property *is* there, but `List<T>`is implementing it [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44a9ty12.aspx).

To convince yourself of this, you can do:

```
List<T> genericList = new List<T>();
IList explicitIList = genericList;

bool isReadOnly = explicitIList.IsReadOnly;
```

This should compile.

You might also want to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598714/implicit-vs-explicit-interface-implementation) and this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx) on how to implement interfaces explicitly, and how to refer to an explicitly implemented member on a type from outside the type.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the IList section:

IList implements ICollection

```
    public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
    {
        public List();
        public List(int capacity);
        public List(IEnumerable<T> collection);
        public int Capacity { get; set; }

        #region IList Members

        int IList.Add(object item);
        bool IList.Contains(object item);
        void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex);
        int IList.IndexOf(object item);
        void IList.Insert(int index, object item);
        void IList.Remove(object item);
        bool IList.IsFixedSize { get; }
        bool IList.IsReadOnly { get; }
        bool ICollection.IsSynchronized { get; }
        object ICollection.SyncRoot { get; }
        object IList.this[int index] { get; set; }

        #endregion

...and so on

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is implemented explicitly. So you shoud access its members in such way(explicitly casting it to interface)
((ICollection)list).IsReadOnly;

Answer (score 0):

From the disassemble code in .NET reflector of System.Collections.Generic.List, it does contain `IsReadOnly` property.

```
 bool ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly { get; }
```