# How can a concrete class hide a member of the interface that it implements

Tags: c#, .net

I will give an example from .NET.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDictionary
```

Here you can see ConcurrentDictionary implementing dictionary interfaces. However I can't access `Add<TKey,TValue>` method from a ConcurrentDictionary instance. How is this possible?

```
IDictionary<int, int> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
dictionary.Add(3, 3); //no errors

ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
concurrentDictionary.Add(3, 3); //Cannot access private method here
```

**Update:**

I know how I can access it but I didn't know explicitly implementing an interface could allow changing access modifiers to internal. It still doesn't allow making it private though. Is this correct? A more detailed explanation about that part would be helpful. Also I would like to know some valid use cases please.

Comment: Explicit interface implementations do not change the access modifiers. They change _how_ you can access the members that were implemented that way (i.e. require you to use a variable of the interface type).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129857/is-the-use-of-explicit-interface-implementation-meant-for-hiding-functionality for some comments on usage

Comment: The default visibility level inside classes is `private` opposed to `package` in java. Explicit interface implementations are private, so no, your assumption is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is implemented as an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx), meaning you need a variable of the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` type to access it.

See the documentation of [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), under the Explicit Interface Implementations section.

If you cast the concurrent dictionary to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you will be able to call `Add` on it.

---

> I didn't know explicitly implementing an interface could allow changing access modifiers to internal. It still doesn't allow making it private though. Is this correct?

No, this is not correct.

Explicit interface implementations do not change the access modifiers. They change how you can access the members that were implemented that way (i.e. require you to use a variable of the interface type). They are still *public* members, but can only be accessed using the interface type, not the implementing type.

Answer (score 7):

Because the `IDictionary.Add` method is [explicitly implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267263.aspx) by ConcurrentDictionary.

To access it from the class without having to declare the variable as IDictionary, cast it to the required interface:

```
((IDictionary)concurrentDictionary).Add(3, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is done through explicit interface implementation

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    void SomeInterface.SomeMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now when you have a reference to a `SomeClass` object, you will not see the `SomeMethod` method available. In order to call it you would have to cast the object back to `ISomeInterface`...

```
((ISomeInterface)mySomeClass).SomeMethod();
```

This is one of the more under-utilizied useful features of C# imo

Answer (score 2):

Explicit interface implementation. For a simpler example:

```
public interface IFoo {
    void Bar();
}
public class Foo : IFoo {
    void IFoo.Bar() { ... }
}
```

here `Bar` is not on the public API of `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

the interface is implemented explicitly. you can not access to `Add` method using an instance of A class in the following example.

```
public interface IA
{
    void Add();
}

public class A : IA
{
    void IA.Add()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier has not been changed; `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` has defined the method `IDictionary.Add` through explicit interface implementation, and has not implemented an `Add` method.

If you look at the [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), you will see that no `Add` method exists (so `concurrentDictionary.Add(3, 3);` would be analogous to calling `concurrentDictionary.MethodThatDoesntExist(3, 3);`). However, under the [Explicit Interface Implementations section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx#ExplicitInterfaceImplementationTableToggle), you can see that there are methods `ICollection.Add` and `IDictionary.Add`.

This feature allows a class to implement multiple interfaces that share a method name without requiring the implementation to be the same for each interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everbody for great answers, one of the deleted answers confused me about the access modifiers. I was able to find some nice explanations from the linked questions.

[Implicit and Explicit Interface Implementations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx) by Michael Hopcroft

[Some use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6129922/205859) by Jon Skeet

[Implementing IDisposable explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3119288/205859)

[Design Guidelines for Explicit Member Implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/11/15/50721.aspx) by Brad Abrams

[Odious ambiguous overloads, part one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/04/05/569085.aspx) & [part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/04/06/570126.aspx) by Eric Lippert