# Implicit <> Explicit interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, implicit, explicit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C#: Interfaces - Implicit and Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation)
>   [implicit vs explicit interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598714/implicit-vs-explicit-interface-implementation)

Hello

Can anyone explain me what the difference is between an implicit and explicit interface?

Thanks!

Comment: About a dozen exact dupes in the Related list....

Comment: yet the answers here are better, funny how that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicit interface implementation is where you have a method with the same signature of the interface.

An explicit interface implementation is where you explicitly declare which interface the method belongs to.

```
interface I1
{
    void implicitExample();
}

interface I2
{
    void explicitExample();
}


class C : I1, I2
{
    void implicitExample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I1.implicitExample()");
    }


    void I2.explicitExample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I2.explicitExample()");
    }
}
```

MSDN: [**implicit and explicit interface implementations**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx)

Comment: What is the difference in use then? Why would you prefer one above another?

Comment: When you have 2 interfaces with the same method signature, you could explicitly declare 2 methods that implement the method for each. Or if you want it to be clear that a method is there for implementing the interface you can explicitly declare so. Implicit declaration exists because mostly you don't really need to declare explicitly, and the interface implementation can be assumed.

Answer (score 10):

When you implement an interface explicitlty, the methods on that interface will only be visible if the object is referenced as the interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   void Bar();
}

public interface IWhatever
{
   void Method();
}

public class MyClass : IFoo, IWhatever
{
   public void IFoo.Bar() //Explicit implementation
   {

   }

   public void Method() //standard implementation
   {

   }
}
```

If somewhere in your code you have a reference to this object:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.Bar(); //will not compile

IFoo mc = new MyClass();
mc.Bar(); //will compile
```

For the standard implementation, it doesn't matter how you reference the object:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.Method(); //compiles just fine
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicit simply means that you specify the interface, implicit means that you don't.

For example:

```
interface A
{
  void A();
}

interface B
{
  void A();
}

class Imp : A
{
    public void A() // Implicit interface implementation
    {

    }
}

class Imp2 : A, B
{
    public void A.A() // Explicit interface implementation
    {

    }

    public void B.A() // Explicit interface implementation
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So, public void A in the class Imp is an implicit interface, because it is created within that class, and doesn't have a reference to interface A (not A.A() ). If it would've been A.A() It would have been an explicit interface?

Whats the difference in use then?

Comment: @Killerwes - That's the _implementation_ side, and as such your are correct. I hase to be explicit in `Imp2` as both interfaces declare the same member. In calling code you need the correct interface reference in order to call the different explicit implementations of `Imp2`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to know why explicit implementation exists, that's because you may implement the same method (name and signature) from more than one interface; then if you need different functionality, or just the return types are different, you can't achieve this through simple overloading. then you'll have to use explicit implementation. One example is that `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` and both have `GetEnumerator()` but with different return values.