# Method hiding in C# classes

Tags: c#

I'm looking at `LinkedList` class implementation in C# and I cannot understand how
Add method is hidden.

`LinkedList` implements `ICollection` which has an `Add` method. In the `LinkedList` class code the `Add` method is declared as:

```
void ICollection<T>.Add(T value);
```

How it is possible to have internal method which is declared in the interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interface is implemented explicitly.

Explicilty implemented interface members can only be accessed through an instance of the implemented interface, like so:

```
LinkedList list;
((ICollection)list).Add(...)
```

Check this **SO** question and answer for more information: [implicit vs explicit interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598714/implicit-vs-explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: Another good example of this in .NET are Streams. Most streams implement IDisposable, yet have a public method called "Close" instead of "Dispose".

Comment: Ok but when I have an interface and a class that implements that interface I cannot have a private method that implements interface nor I can miss interface's method from implementation.

Comment: @Jenea: You are not missing the method nor is it private. Think **why** you implement interfaces. You do it to certify that a given `class` will comply with a certain "contract". This is only useful if a consumer of said `class` will access it through an instance of the `interface` it implements (if the consumer were to have access to the `class` instance itself, why use the `interface`?). When accessing through the `interface`, the consumer has access to all methods defined by the `interface`, implicit or explicit.