# Using interfaces on abstract classes in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I'm learning C# coming from C++ and have run into a wall.

I have an abstract class AbstractWidget, an interface IDoesCoolThings, and a class which derives from AbstractWidget called RealWidget:

```
public interface IDoesCoolThings
{
    void DoCool();
}

public abstract class AbstractWidget : IDoesCoolThings
{
    void IDoesCoolThings.DoCool()
    {
        Console.Write("I did something cool.");
    }
}

public class RealWidget : AbstractWidget
{

}
```

When I instantiate a RealWidget object and call DoCool() on it, the compiler gives me an error saying

> 'RealWidget' does not contain a
>   definition for 'DoCool'

I can cast RealWidget object to an IDoesCoolThings and then the call will work, but that seems unnecessary and I also lose polymorphism (AbstractWidget.DoCool() will always be called even if i define RealWidget.DoCool()).

I imagine the solution is simple, but I've tried a variety of things and for the life of me can't figure this one out.

Comment: To have polymorphism in widgets' DoCool(), you'd need to declare the AbstractWidget's one virtual.

Comment: Erg.  I'd read somewhere that virtual was implied for interface methods.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're running into the issue because you used **[*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx)** (EII). When a member is explicitly implemented, it can't be accessed through a class instance -- only through an instance of the interface. In your example, that's why you can't call `DoCool()` unless you cast your instance to `IDoesCoolThings`.

The solution is to make `DoCool()` public and remove the explicit interface implementation:

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget : IDoesCoolThings
{
    public void DoCool()      // DoCool() is part of the abstract class implementation.
    {
        Console.Write("I did something cool.");
    }
}

// ...

var rw = new RealWidget();
rw.DoCool();                  // Works!
```

In general, you use EII in two cases:

- You have a class that must implement two interfaces, each of which contains a member that has an identical name/signature to another member in the other interface.
- You want to *force* clients not to depend on the implementation details of your class, but rather on the interface that's being implemented by your class. (This is considered a good practice by some.)

Comment: God, I thought I'd tried that.  Thanks!  I seemed to have missed this key line in my reference book: "a method deﬁned by using explicit interface implementation cannot be declared as virtual, whereas omitting the interface name allows this behavior."

Comment: I was confused that simply making the method public in the abstract class didn't fix the problem, plus the examples I read didn't define methods as public or private, so I came to believe interface methods are implicitly public and virtual.  Overall, an embarrassing question :).  Thanks though!

Comment: Explicit interface implementation can also be good if it's possible that a derived class' override of a member may wish to return a type which is derived from the base class' implementation.  For example, both `CarFactory` and `ICarFactory` may have `MakeCar()` method which returns `Car`, but `FordCarFactory` may want to have a `MakeCar()` method return a `FordCar`.  That could often be best handled by having a `protected` virtual `DoMakeCar` method that returns `Car`, and having both `ICarFactory.MakeCar` and a non-virtual `CarFactory.MakeCar` method chain to that.

Answer (score 8):

Change your declaration to:

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget : IDoesCoolThings 
{
    public void DoCool()
    { 
        Console.Write("I did something cool."); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The way you implement the interface is explicit implement void IDoesCoolThings.DoCool(), if you choose implicit implement interface.

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget : IDoesCoolThings
{
    public void DoCool()
    {
        Console.Write("I did something cool.");
    }
}
```

Then it will work.

Read this :

[C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation)

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the SO question on implicit and explicit implementation !

Answer (score 1):

You should do it this way:

```
public interface IDoesCoolThings 
{
   void DoCool();
}

public abstract class AbstractWidget 
{
   public void DoCool()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("I did something cool.");
   }
}

public class Widget : AbstractWidget, IDoesCoolThings 
{
}
```

Usage:

```
var widget = new Widget();
widget.DoCool();
```