# Accessing a method of an interface

Tags: c#, interface

I'm starting to work with interfaces and I really don't understand... The situation is this:
there is a webcontrol (called TableControl) which displays a table of items using a repeater. TableControl includes also a line of cursors (first, previous, next, last) that implements paging. The cursors are imported from another webControl (CursorControl). TableControl implements also an interface, in which I declare some method to do paging.

*) CursorControl

```
 public class CursorControl 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private string cursor_value;

    public string CursorValue
    {
        get { return cursor_value; }
        set { cursor_value = value; }
    }

    // Called when cursor is clicked.
    protected void lnkClick_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        cursor_value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }

}
```

*) TableControl

```
public partial class TableControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IPageableControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(isPostBack)
         {
               currentPage = CursorControl.CursorValue;
               OtherPage(currentPage);
          }
    }

    public int currentPage;

    void IPageableControl.OtherPage(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            currentPage = 2;
        else if (i == 1 || i == (-1))
            currentPage += i;
        else
            currentPage = 25;

    }


 }
```

*) Interface

```
   public interface IPageableControl
{
    // Summary:
    //     Go to page
    void OtherPage(int i);
}
```

When a user clicks on a cursor I pass the value to TableControl, which should start the method OtherPage. But it doesn't work, it says that OtherPage is not in the current context.

How can I access a method of an interface??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this line:

```
void IPageableControl.OtherPage(int i)
```

into this:

```
void OtherPage(int i)
```

The first one is explicit, the second is implicit. ([What are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation))

- When you explicitly mention the interface type, you need to convert
  your type to it in-order to access those methods. ([Why implement interface explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103300/c-sharp-why-implement-interface-explicitly))
- When you implicitly implement you just treat it as a
  regular method (the implementation is exactly the same, and the compiler will ensure that it's there so you don't have to worry about it. **In the code you won't see any difference.** *If you do want to see (which helps) you could get a plugin. ReSharper does this very well*).

---

By the way, on Visual Studio, when you want to implement an interface, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) on the interface(s) name and it will ask you how to implement it. It makes it much less tedious because you won't have to type the signatures (method names) by yourself.

[image: Visual Studio Implementing Interfaces]