# How to unit test explicit interface implemented methods?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, xunit, explicit-implementation

I have the following method in a service but I'm failing to call it in my unit test.  The method uses the `async/ await` code but also (and which I think is causing me the problem) has the name of the method with a dot notation which I'm not sure what that does to be honest?  See my example below

**Implementation**

```
async Task<IEnumerable<ISomething>> IMyService.MyMethodToTest(string bla)
{
    ...
}
```

**Unit test**

```
[Fact]
public void Test_My_Method()
{
   var service = new MyService(...);
   var result = await service.MyMethodToTest("");  // This is not available ?
}
```

**Update**

Have tried the suggestions but it does not compile with the following error message

```
await operator can only be used with an async method.
```

Comment: IMyService.MyMethodToTest implies that MyMethodToTest is an implementation for the method MyMethodToTest of the interface IMyService

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *explicit interface implementations* can only be invoked on an expression of the *interface* type, not the implementing type.

Just cast the service to the interface type first, or use a different variable:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_My_Method()
{
    IMyService serviceInterface = service;
    var result = await serviceInterface.MyMethodToTest("");
}
```

Or

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_My_Method()
{
    var result = await ((IMyService) service).MyMethodToTest("");
}
```

Personally I prefer the former approach.

Note the change of return type from `void` to `Task`, and making the method `async`. This has nothing to do with explicit interface implementation, and is just about writing async tests.

Comment: thank you for your help although it still doesn't work, I've updated my question with the error message

Comment: @Jamie: Well yes, that's an entirely different problem though. You need to make your test method async. Will update my answer, but basically you should research one problem at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var result = await ((IMyService)service).MyMethodToTest("");
```

There are many [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103300/why-implement-interface-explicitly) for [implementing an interface explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Or

```
[Fact]
public async void Test_My_Method()
{
   IMyService service = new MyService(...);
   var result = await service.MyMethodToTest("");  
}
```

You should use at least xUnit.net 1.9 to be able to use `async`. If you are using a lower version then you should use this:

```
[Fact]
public void Test_My_Method()
{
    IMyService service = new MyService(...);
    var result = await service.MyMethodToTest("");
    Task task = service.MyMethodToTest("")
           .ContinueWith(innerTask =>
           {
               var result = innerTask.Result;
               // ... assertions here ...
           });

    task.Wait();
}
```