# Class that implements IDisposable without Dispose function?

Tags: c#, idisposable, websocket-sharp

I just pulled in `WebSocketSharp` via nuget.
It's class `WebSocket` implements `IDisposable` but doesn't seem to have a `Dispose` method.
How is that possible? I thought if you implement an interface you also have to implement all of it's properties/methods.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Explicitly implemented. See https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/WebSocket.cs#L3073 ( and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103300/why-implement-interface-explicitly)

Comment: Just an idea, maybe somebody can confirm this - if the interface method is implemented explicitly (`explicit interface implementation`), would it be displayed here? Maybe that is the case.

Comment: It has an explicit implementation and has a Close() method instead. It's a common pattern.

Comment: @Chips_100 It would not be displayed here. It's not public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GitHub in [source](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/WebSocket.cs):

```
#region Explicit Interface Implementations

/// <summary>
/// Closes the WebSocket connection, and releases all associated resources.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This method closes the connection with <see cref="CloseStatusCode.Away"/>.
/// </remarks>
void IDisposable.Dispose ()
{
  close (new CloseEventArgs (CloseStatusCode.Away), true, true, false);
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Thank you, very interesting!