# Can I satisfy an interface with a compatible return type?

Tags: c#, covariance

I have the following snippet

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IInventoryItem {}
public class      InventoryItem : IInventoryItem {}

public interface IInventory
{
    IEnumerable<IInventoryItem> Items { get; }
}

public class Inventory : IInventory
{
    public  IEnumerable<InventoryItem>  Items            => items;
    //      IEnumerable<IInventoryItem> IInventory.Items => items;

    private InventoryItem[] items = new InventoryItem[0];
}
```

And I get the following error message:

> error CS0738: `Inventory` does not implement interface member `IInventory.Items.get` and the best implementing candidate `Inventory.Items.get` return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<InventoryItem>` does not match interface member return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IInventoryItem>`

Adding an explicit implementation of `IInventory.Items.get` does exactly the right thing, but why is it necessary?

The question is: why is `IEnumerable<InventoryItem>` not an `IEnumerable<IInventoryItem>` if `InventoryItem[]` is?

**EDIT:**

A bit about why this is interesting:
My assumptions:

- `Items.get` will always return an `IEnumerable<T>` that is a valid `IEnumerable<IInventoryItem>`

Comment: Leaving aside generic variance, this requirement has *always* been the case: if an interface says that the return type is `object`, you can't implement that with a method returning `string`. The same is true when overriding.

Comment: why you need interface if you will use concrete type ?

Comment: The interfaces will live in another assembly, that's why I need them.

Comment: that's what happen when someone tell you tu put interface everywhere because it's good. It eventually get used badly.

Answer (score 4):

It's necessary because `IInventoryItem` is **not** (and can not be) limited to only be implemented by `InventoryItem`.

If you (or anyone else) will write another class that implements the `IInventoryItem` interface, any class that implements the `IInventory` interface will be able to handle that, since it only deals with the `IInventoryItem` interface and doesn't know or care about concrete implementations.

If the compiler allowed to write the `Inventory` class like in your question, then it would not be able to handle any other class that implements the `IInventoryItem` interface.

For clarification:

The `Items` property returns an `IEnumerable<InventoryItem>`.
If you added a different class implementing the `IInventoryItem`, and that class did not inherit from `InventoryItem`, your property will not be able to return an `IEnumerable` of it.
Suppose you add this class:

```
public class MyNotRelatedInventoryItem : IInventoryItem
{ /* implementation here */ }
```

Your current `Items` property will never be able to hold an `IEnumerable` of `MyNotRelatedInventoryItem`, since it's not related in any way to your `InventoryItem` class.

Comment: One upvote, two downvotes. I'd sure like to know what's wrong with my answer...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems that you think that some of the interfaces know about the implementations, but they don't.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question about why he can't return a concrete type implementing the required interface in a get.

Comment: @Steinbitglis I don't know why it seems that way to you - Nothing I wrote indicates that IMO.

Comment: @OwenPauling Yes it does. That's exactly the reason.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I just thought that because you wrote that IInventoryItem was limited. I'm struggling a bit to get an overview, so I might just be a bit slow. And I din't dare downvote for that reason :-)

Comment: "IInventoryItem is **not** (and can not be) limited "

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103300/why-implement-interface-explicitly) have a lot of good reasons (and some explanation) to use interfaces. I recommend you take look @ZoharPeled

Comment: Can you clarify with example what do you mean by "handle" in the last sentence?  `If the compiler allowed to write the Inventory class like in your question, then it would not be able to handle any other class that implements the IInventoryItem interface.`

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Thank you for the link, but I don't see how it's relevant to the question or to my answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Your question and comments doubts look like a misunderstood of the Interface concepts, use cases and reason to be. I thought those answers could be helpful. I'm sorry if it's not =)

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev I've edited my answer to to clarify.

Comment: Since IEnumerable is a covariant you can not add items to it, so it shouldn't be a problem... that's my understanding?

Comment: The real reason is given in the answer to the question linked as duplicate: it appears to be a limitation of the CLR.

Comment: Zohar Peled I'm sorry! My mistake, I should mention @Steinbitglis , not you. I completely agree with your answer. ^^'

Comment: @Henrik While I'm not pretending to have a better understanding of c# then that of Jon Skeet, the reason he is talking about in his answer is very general and is suited as an answer to every question about why a specific product is designed the way it is. I believe my answer here is more specific.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. As @Steinbitglis pointed out, because you cannot add items, there is no need for `Inventory` to "handle" other classes.

Comment: @Henrik Since this answer has 2 downvotes (as of now), apparently you are not the only one that disagree with it. However, this issue is not related at all to the fact that the type of the property type is an `IEnumerable` - you would still get a compiler error if the property type would be `IInventoryItem` in the interface and `InventoryItem` in the class.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I addition to what Zohar already mentioned, here´s how you can achieve what you want with generics:

```
public interface IInventoryItem {}
public class      InventoryItem : IInventoryItem {}
public interface IInventory<T> where T : IInventoryItem
{
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; } 
}

public class Inventory : IInventory<InventoryItem>
{
    public  IEnumerable<InventoryItem>  Items            => items;    
    private InventoryItem[] items = new InventoryItem[0];
}
```

However this has the drawback, that the entire interface `IInventory` is generic, as properties can´t be generic. To circumvent this, you could create a `GetItems`-method instea, which *can* be generic.

When you have an interface, you have to **implement it with the exact same signature as defined by that interface**. For the same reason you can´t do the following:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    A A { get; }
}
class A : MyInterface
{
    public B A { get; private set; } // this will NOT implement the interface, although B derives from A
}
class B : A { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your property return type does not match the interface's, so the compiler doesn't see it as the interface implementation. So you need to change it to

```
public  IEnumerable<IInventoryItem> Items => items;
```

instead of

```
public  IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Items => items;
```

Since it exists an implicit conversion from `InvetoryItem` to `IInventoryItem`, the compiler is OK

This is possible because you only return the value, and the compiler knows every `InvetoryItem` in your array can be converted to an `IInventoryItem` type without ever throwing an exception.

If your interface looked like this:

```
public interface IInventory
{
    IEnumerable<IInventoryItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

That would not be possible, the following code

```
public IEnumerable<IInventoryItem> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; }
}
```

would raise the following compiling error:

> Error    CS0266  
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'ConsoleApplication1.InventoryItem[]'. **An explicit conversion exists** (are you missing a cast?)

This means that the compiler cannot implicitly convert any `IInventoryItem` to `InventoryItem` because it has no way to make sure this conversion will always succeed.

You have to explicitly convert like this :

```
public IEnumerable<IInventoryItem> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = (InventoryItem[])value; }
}
```

but an exception can occur if the array is not made entirely of `InvetoryItem` objects.

Comment: Is the setter relevant when it's not in the interface?

Comment: @Steinbitglis Not really, just to make the point on implicit conversion for output and explicit on input.

Comment: nitpicking: A property is not a function and a method's return type is not a part of it's signature.