# Can an IDispose objects not have an available Dispose method

Tags: c#, idisposable, filehelpers

I am using [FileHelpers](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers) in one project, and the class `MultiRecordEngine`

```
public sealed class MultiRecordEngine
    : EventEngineBase<object>, IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

This class implements `IDisposable`, BUT don't have a public Dispose method...

```
MultiRecordEngine eng = null;
eng.Dispose(); // <---- Results in compilation error
```

Inspecting [this class code on GitHub](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/726b29b005b91cca379f75ef28000b04b7ac4fc4/FileHelpers/Engines/MultiRecordEngine.cs) I can see the method implemented explicitly here, line 913:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    Close();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

So... **Why cannot I invoke the method? Is this intended, and if so, is it a good practice, and in what circumstances?**

Comment: Seems like a pain in the rear, and counter-intuitive. I'd like to hear if anyone can offer some benefit to explicitly implementing IDisposable.

Comment: similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119288/why-would-a-class-implement-idisposable-explicitly-instead-of-implicitly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577252/explicit-implementation-of-idisposable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408415/why-explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: @hatchet A possible reason is that it is nice to have the Intellisense list uncluttered by Dispose() that will 99% of the time not be invoked directly.

Comment: @KeithPayne - except that having Dispose() appear in the Intellisense list may be the tip off needed to make the programmer aware that it's something that needs disposing. If it doesn't appear, they may just assume it doesn't implement IDisposable.

Comment: @hatchet: The primary case where explicit implementation makes sense is when a class implements an interface that implements `IDisposable` (e.g. `IEnumerator<T>`) but the `Dispose` method does nothing.  Microsoft suggests that things with methods called e.g. `Close`, `Shutdown`, etc. may implement `Dispose` explicitly to suggest that it's redundant with those other methods, but I really dislike that pattern since there's nothing to indicate what methods are adequate substitutes for `Dispose` (some classes may keep resources after `Close` to allow for being re-opened).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's implemented explicitly, so you need to cast to `IDisposable`:

```
((IDisposable)eng).Dispose();
```

explicitly implemented members are only accessible through the interface, not the implementing class.

Comment: Ashamed of myself. I always thought the explicitly implementation had no effect in the client code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you can invoke the method by casting to `IDisposable`:

```
((IDisposable)eng).Dispose();
```

You can also properly use the class in a using block:

```
using (MultiRecordEngine eng = new MultiRecordEngine())
{
..
}
```