# Why doesn't the C# Dictionary implement all of IDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, idictionary

I wanted to create a Dictionary-like object and thought the correct way would be to implement the `IDictionary<K,V>` interface, and use composition to include the underlying dictionary.  I began with the below (`K`=`string`, `V`=`int`)

```
public class DictionaryLikeObject : IDictionary<string,int> {
  Dictionary<string,int> _backingDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
}
```

Then I used Visual Studio's "Implement Interface" ability to stub out all the cover methods that I would need.

Three methods of `IDictionary` do not seem to exist in `Dictionary`:

```
void Add(KeyValuePair<string, int> item);
void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, int>[] array, int arrayIndex);
bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, int> item);
```

Yet [the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) clearly indicates that `Dictionary` implements `IDictionary`.  So I would have expected these three methods to be available.  To copy from the documentation, the definition of `Dictionary<K,V>`

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
public class Dictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>, 
ICollection<KeyValuePair<K, V>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>, 
IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
```

These three missing methods, I believe, are found in `ICollection<>`.  But so are other methods such as `Clear()` that `Dictionary` does have.

**Question 1:**  How can C# get away without implementing these three, and why is this so?  I suspect this is a compiler error (for my reasoning, see below).
**Question 2:**  Alternatively, what am I missing?

Here's why I think it might be a compiler error.  Examine the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
IDictionary<string, int> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
KeyValuePair<string, int> item = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("test", 1);
//dictionary1.Add(item); // compile error: No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 argument
dictionary2.Add(item); // works like a charm
Debug.WriteLine(@"dictionary2[""test""] = {0}", dictionary2["test"]); // outputs: dictionary2["test"] = 1
```

The method `void Add(KeyValuePair<string, int> item)` appears not to be in `Dictionary<string,int>` (since it doesn't compile), but it is in `IDictionary<string,int>`, and somehow the compiler does properly find an implementation of it.  **Question 3:** What's going on?

Note that the Microsoft documentation for `Dictionary<K,V>` does not specify these three methods.

Lastly, in my actual implementation, I ended up using

```
IDictionary<string,int> _backingDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

instead of

```
Dictionary<string,int> _backingDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

so that all three methods could easily work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does implement these methods, it just does so explicitly.  Hence you must access it via the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface.

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = ...;
KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = ...;
map.Add(pair);  // Compilation Error
((IDictionary<string, string>)map).Add(pair);  // Works
```

Explicit implementation works by specifying precisely which interface method an instance method implements at the point of definition.  For example

```
interface IFoo {
  void Method(); 
}

class C1 : IFoo {
  // Implicitly implements IFoo.Method
  public void Method() { }
}

class C2 : IFoo {
  // Explicitly implements IFoo.Method
  void IFoo.Method() { }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly my first guess. Do you know why this isn't specified in the MSDN documentation? Also, why did they hide those methods?

Comment: @the_drow, I'm unsure why they don't make that distinction in the documentation nor am I 100% sure why they made the choice.  My first instinct for the latter is they wanted to provide a single overload of Add by default.

Comment: @the_drow: It is actually specified in the MSDN documentation. You just have to scroll way down to "Explicit Interface Implementations"

Comment: So the explicit/implicit answer nails this question. JaredPar's answer, coupled with a careful reading Microsoft's documentation of explicit/implicit implementation [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) and the StackOverflow thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation) was truly helpful.  Also, thanks to Daniel for pointing out that the MSDN documentation does list "explicit implementations".