# String a; a.ToBoolean(...) & IConvertible

Tags: c#, interface

Playing around in Mono 2.10 REPL:

```
csharp> string a = "true";
csharp> a.ToBoolean(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
{interactive}(1,4): error CS1061: Type `string' does not contain a definition fo
r `ToBoolean' and no extension method `ToBoolean' of type `string' could be foun
d (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.2\lib\mono\4.0\mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related
 to previous error)


csharp> ((IConvertible)a).ToBoolean(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
true
csharp>
```

According to docs, `System.String` implements IConvertible. If this is true, why does

```
a.ToBoolean(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

fail?

Why do I have to cast it to IConvertible to make ToBoolean work?

Comment: In any case, you should not be using those conversion methods but instead, the parsing functions defined for the type or the `Convert` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the documentation for `ToBoolan()` for `string` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346937.aspx) states:

> This member is [an explicit interface member implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). It can be used only when the `String` instance is cast to an `IConvertible` interface. The recommended alternative is to call the `Convert.ToBoolean(String)` method.

Answer (score 2):

The interface is explicitly implemented.

Comment: Interfaces that are implicitly implemented can be called directly.

Comment: Interfaces are not explicitly implemented, its members (like methods) are. For example, you can implement one member implicitly and another explicitly.

Comment: @svick That's right. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation