# Question About Interfaces

Tags: .net

How is it possible for [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) to implement [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)?  The latter requires implementation of the Add method, and the ReadOnlyCollection does not implement this.  However, ReadOnlyCollection is concrete and can be instantiated...

**Edit**

The following code will not compile on my machine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> people = new List<string>(){
        "Sidney",
        "Jim",
        "Bob"};

    ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyPeople = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(people);
    readOnlyPeople.Add("Frank");
}
```

The call to "Add" in the last statement is now underlined in blue in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: That code won't compile because the `Add` method is _explicitly_ implemented.  You have to cast to `IList` before you can access it.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Where is it 'explicitly' implemented?  I thought interfaces didn't support implementations of methods...

Comment: You're right that interfaces don't themselves implement the method.  Explicit implementation is a special thing in C# - [see this answer for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation).

Comment: Sorry, thanks Paul.  I just googled explicit implementation and interfaces.  Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does implement Add, the implementation simply throws a `NotSupportedException`.

The implementation uses "[explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)", which is a way of implementing interfaces without directly exposing interface methods as public on the implementing class.  It's most useful when you have a class that implements more than one interface that defines the same member (see the example at the link).  Basically, it looks something like this:

```
public interface IList<T>
{
    int Add(object value);
    // and a whole bunch of other stuff...
}

public class ReadOnlyCollection<T> : IList<T>
{
    int IList<T>.Add(object value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Notice how the add method isn't public, so if you have an instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, you can't directly call `Add` on it.  What you can do however, if you want to see the exception, is cast your instance to the interface:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyPeople = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(people);
((IList<string>)readonlyPeople).Add("Frank"); // <-- bang!
```

The other way you could achieve it is to declare your variable as an `IList<T>` directly:

```
IList<string> readOnlyPeople = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(people);
readOnlyPeople.Add("Frank"); // <-- this should go 'bang!' too
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jon.  I thought I was going crazy, otherwise:)

Answer (score 1):

It does implement the Add method, but the implementation of that method just throws a [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx).