# why is there no Dispose method on HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using-statement

`HttpWebReponse` implements `IDisposable` interface, but why is there no `Dispose` method. It only contains `Close` method. Will be `using` pattern still available for this class?

Comment: The [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) should be a Dispose method, as specified here: [WebResponse.Dispose Method @ msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928381.aspx)

Comment: BTW - Perhaps this changed at some point. now `HttpWebResponse response = ...;'` `response.Dispose();` compiles.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

HttpWebResponse [implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356598.aspx) IDisposable interface explicitly. So you can call `Dispose` only when you cast HttpWebResponse to `IDisposable`. The `Close` method of HttpWebResponse calls Dispose internally.

```
HttpWebResponse response = // assigned from somewhere
IDisposable disposableResponse = response as IDisposable;

disposableResponse.Dispose();
```

Since `HttpWebResponse` implements `IDisposable` you can use it with an using-statement.

```
HttpWebResponse response = // assigned from somewhere

using(response) {
  // do your work;
}
```

Comment: @user705414: see this questio on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation

Comment: why is it implemented explicitly?

Comment: @jgauffin, because (someone at) Microsoft thinks it will make your code more readable to write `response.Close();` instead of `response.Dispose();`. The same reason that all IO/stream classes must be `Close`d.

Comment: It seems that the opposite is true. `Dispose()` calls `Close()` internally. Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebResponse.cs,fb515b1af6c9f830