# What does IDisposable.Dispose() as a method name mean?

Tags: c#, methods, interface, declaration

I was just tidying up some code when I found this region in the class:

```
    #region IDisposable Members

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
        } 

     #endregion
```

Now understand that this is implementing the Dispose method for the IDisposable interface and I know that the class declaration says that this class will implement the IDisposable interface.

What I don't get is why it reads:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
```

And not:

```
public void Dispose()
```

I guess that the IDisposable.Dispose indicated explicitly that this is the Dispose that implements the IDisposable interface?  Is this correct and what's the advantage of doing this?

Comment: You should read about Explicit and Implicit implementation of interfaces in C# see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation

Comment: wow, that actually gives more information than the Microsoft Article! you should have put your comment as an answer!

Comment: I agree with @AidanO - post it as an answer.

Comment: I tried, but SO turned it into a comment. vote it up all you like though :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

It means that only a variable of type `IDisposable` can call `Dispose` on this class.

Doing so "hides" the `Dispose` method when used with a variable of the class type - it will not be able to call it directly without first casting to `IDisposable`. It is possible that the implementer did this on purpose.

Additionally, if the class were to implement its own `Dispose` (or inherit/implement from a class/interface that also defines a `Dispose` method), this will allow multiple implementations to exist.

Comment: But why it might be a good idea here? Try the **Dispose Pattern** documentation (maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx just before `#code-snippet-7` , but those links seem to rot faster than the apples from our tree): if the “natural” disposal method name is `Close` (as for a `File`), you want you users doing that, so you ensure they can only use `Dispose` via `IDisposable` – at least that is how I read it: “When doing so, it is important that you make the Close implementation identical to Dispose and _consider implementing the IDisposable.Dispose method explicitly_.” …

Comment: … but I suspect that a lot of explicit implementations of `IDisposable.Dispose()` are misunderstandings or coppy & paced run wild.

Answer (score 0):

That's an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Useful if a class implements several interfaces that have the same methods.