# Cast a base class to ISerializable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I've implemented ISerializable in both a child class and a parent class, like this:

```
class CircuitElement : ISerializable
{
    ...
    protected void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
        info.AddValue("ID", ID);
    }
}

class Bus : CircuitElement, ISerializable
{
    ...
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
        ((ISerializable)base).GetObjectData(info,context);
        info.AddValue("Voltage", Voltage);
        info.AddValue("BaseVoltage", BaseVoltage);
        info.AddValue("Location", Location);
    }
}
```

But in the child class `Bus`, I'm getting the error `Use of keyword base is not valid in this context`. I know I can just implement the interface implicitly on the parent `CircuitElement` class, and then I don't have to worry about the conversion, but was under the impression that explicit implementation is more appropriate for this scenario (for reasons akin to those presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/143425/996592)

Is there a way to do the conversion, or am I stuck implementing the `ISerializable` interface in the parent class implicitly?

Comment: This is already invalid: `protected void ISerializable.GetObjectData` - when you use explicit interface implementation, you don't specify an access modifier. And then you *can't* call that implementation from a re-implementation.

Comment: Yep, sorry. copy-paste mistake on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I disagree with the perspective presented in the answer you linked to. Explicit interface implementation is simply more problematic, for *exactly* the reason you've given: it really doesn't play nicely with inheritance.

If you're reimplementing an interface which has been implemented explicitly, there's just *no way* of calling that implementation on an object of a type which reimplements the same interface, including from within the code of that reimplementation.

Two options:

- Use implicit interface implementation instead. Personally I usually find this simpler. I only use explicit interface implementation when the interface has members which don't really make sense when you're thinking about the class itself.
- Continue to use explicit interface implementation, but make that implementation *just* call a protected virtual method. You can then override that virtual method in the derived class and call the base implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll go with an implicit interface.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert using `"base"` keyword. Actually you can't use `"base"` keyword in this context. You should simply call the base method if you wanna include the parent information using `"base.GetObjectData"` **if you implement the `"ISerializable"` interface in the implicit way** and it will call the parent method with owner of caller instance.

This behavior is one of the simple things in the Object-Oriented model and you can't change that. On the other hand you can use `"virtual"` keyword and try overriding the parent method (in this case I don't think that you need this method).

I think you should take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation?lq=1) on stackoverflow, there are some great answers about the ways of implementing interfaces.

Also there is a perfect manual about **Polymorphism** on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It will help you to understand why you can'n convert `"base"` and you will find some technics to do that in the other specified ways.

**My Idea:**

Using `"dynamic"` keyword and `"ExpandoObject"` is a better idea for creating a dynamic model and do serialization things on it. In my personal opinion it's much more faster in many cases, also it's so simple to implement.

Hope it help.