# Something about .NET inheritance/casting that I don't understand?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, casting

See the following simple casting example:

```
int i = 1000;
object o = (object)i; // cast

i.CompareTo(1000);
o.CompareTo(1000); // error
```

I understand why the last line generates an error. Unlike ints, objects don't implement `IComparable` and therefore don't expose the `CompareTo` method. The following also generates an error:

```
string s = (string)i; // cast error
```

Since there's no inheritance between ints and strings, casting will not work here. Now, take a look at this:

```
AudioRender a = new AudioRender();
IBaseFilter b = (IBaseFilter)a; // cast

a.Run(1000); // error
b.Run(1000);
```

(*These classes come from the [DirectShowNet library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).*)

I don't understand this. The cast does not generate an error and throws no exceptions at runtime, so I assume that AudioRender implements IBaseFilter. However, AudioRender does not expose any of IBaseFilter's methods, indicating that my assumption above is wrong...

If `a` implements `b`, why doesn't `a` expose the methods of `b`?
Else, if `a` does not implement `b`, why can `a` be casted to `b`?
Also, can I reproduce this behaviour without the use of DirectShowNet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>It is likely that AudioRender implements [Conversion Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).</strike>

However, having looked at code it seems that both AudioRender and IBaseFilter are Com Imports:

```
[ComImport, Guid("e30629d1-27e5-11ce-875d-00608cb78066")]
public class AudioRender { }


[ComImport, ("56a86895-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IBaseFilter { .. }
```

As you can see AudioRender import class does not implement IBaseFilter, so you will not see it in intellisense, but it is likely that underlying COM object implements it, hence why you can cast.

Comment: Even if it does, how does that answer the question?

Comment: because it would allow you to cast to another type without it being a base type

Comment: Sure, but that's not what the OP is seeing. The OP is getting an error _unless_ they cast. What you said is about not needing to cast at all.

Comment: Well, if it used explicit cast operator it would require you to cast, but this or the other way, OP is seeing this behavior because both type and interface are COM Imports anyway.

Comment: +1 for actually looking up the types (eventually :)) rather than just speculating.

Answer (score 14):

It is difficult to tell without access to the documentation of the `AudioRender` class, but a reasonable guess would be that the implementation of `Run` on it is a [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx).

```
public AudioRender : IBaseFilter
{
  IBaseFilter.Run(...) {...}
}
```

That means you can only access the `Run` method when you access it through a `IBaseFilter` reference.

Comment: +1 for explicit interface implementation, I did not know that was possible in .NET. If only I could accept multiple answers.

Answer (score 6):

Without seeing the source code of the types, I think `AudioRender` implements the interface `IBaseFilter` [explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-interfaces-implicit-and-explicit-implementation), so you won't see the methods of the interface in IntelliSense on `AudioRender`.

Answer (score 2):

> If a implements b, why doesn't a expose the methods of b?

this can be achieved by [implementing explicitly the interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx)

> Else, if a does not implement b, why can a be casted to b?

Because indeed `a` implements `b`.

> Also, can I reproduce this behaviour without the use of DirectShowNet?

Yes sure you can, see this example from the above link (`obj.Paint()` is a compiler error):

```
    interface IControl
    {
        void Paint();
    }

    public class SampleClass : IControl
    {
        void IControl.Paint()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
        }
    }

void doit(){
    SampleClass obj = new SampleClass();
    //obj.Paint();  // Compiler error.

    IControl c = (IControl)obj;
    c.Paint();  // Calls IControl.Paint on SampleClass.
}
```