# How do you override properties in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've got an interface say **IMyInterface** which is implemented by a class **MyClass** how do I declare properties with getters and setters that override rather than masking the ones in the interface?

For example for the interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    String MyProperty {get;}
}
```

If I do this I'm hiding the interface property

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public String MyProperty 
    { 
        get 
        {
             return "Whatever";
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do this I get an error saying that **MyProperty** can't be public:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public String IMyInterface.MyProperty 
    { 
        get 
        {
             return "Whatever";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When implementing interface members explicitly you don't use accessibility modifiers.

Comment: Not sure as what you mean i guess that is what an interface is supposed to do

Comment: Are they then implicitly public?

Comment: Interface members are public for the interface. When you implement them explicitly they can only be accessed through the interface. See [Explicit interface member implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591.aspx) specification.

Comment: I'm talking about the implementing class where it complains about me using the public modifier on my declaration of IMyInterface.MyProperty

Comment: @OmarKooheji i guess this should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation

Answer (score 5):

As interfaces have no implementations, *overriding* is a concept that does not apply to interfaces. Therefore interface member don't need to be `virtual`.

You override when using **class inheritance**. You need to make them `virtual` in a base class, and use the `override` keyword in a subclass:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; }
}

class FooBase : IFoo
{
    public virtual string Bar { get; protected set; }
}

class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override string Bar { get; protected set; }
}
```

If you **explicitly implement an interface**, you need no `public` modifier since the member is only visible when consumer use the interface type:

```
class FooExplicit : IFoo
{
    // IFoo f = new FooExplicit(); <- Bar is visible
    // FooExplicit fe = new FooExplicit(); <- there is no Bar
    string IFoo.Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

As `IFoo.Bar` is still tied *only to the interface* it's still implicitly `public`. In Java you could add the `public` modifier if you like (optional of course). C# in contrast *prohibits* this.

Comment: Are they no implicitly virtual in the interface? I'm not creating an abstract class.

Comment: Actually you cannot *override* interface members, but only base class members. You *implement* interfaces, and you override *implementations* from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
    public virtual int P1
    {
        get { return 42; }
        set { }
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override int P1
    {
        get { return 18; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are they then implicitly public?

interface memebers are implicity `public`, you can use any access specifier with the interface members in the interface.

[interface C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx)

> Interface members are automatically public, and they can't include any
>   access modifiers.

For comment:

> I'm talking about the implementing class where it complains about me
>   using the public modifier on my declaration of IMyInterface.MyProperty

Since you are doing [Explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229034%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), The method can only be called against an interface object, It can't be called against the class object. Since all members of interface are implicitly `public` it would be redundant and that is why not allowed.

See this article: [Explicit interface implementation – to hide interface member in implementing type](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/02/07/c.net-little-wonders-explicit-interface-implementation.aspx)

> To implement an interface explicitly, you drop the public access
>   specifier (all interface members are public), and predicate the method
>   name with the interface name and dot

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by hidding? Your first example is normal, implicit implementation of interface's property. You're not hidding it, you're implementing it.

Your second example is explicite interface implementation - it cannot be public by design. You will only be able to call it when your variable type will be of `IMyInterface`.

You can of course mark your property as `virtual` in implementing class to allow it to be overriden in iheritting classes, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

this may help [Interface Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
interface IEmployee{
string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}

int Counter
{
    get;
}}     
public class Employee : IEmployee    
{
public static int numberOfEmployees;

private string name;
public string Name  // read-write instance property
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name = value;
    }
}

private int counter;
public int Counter  // read-only instance property
{
    get
    {
        return counter;
    }
}

public Employee()  // constructor
{
    counter = ++counter + numberOfEmployees;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a property in an interface doesn't actually provide an implementation of the property on the interface.

i.e. By stating

```
public interface IMyInterface
...
    String MyProperty {get;}
```

You are in fact just requiring that implementations of the interface must provide a property `MyProperty` which has a getter. I do agree however that the syntax can easily be confused with [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), but in the case of the interface, there is no backing field.

*Update*

Explicit interface implementation is used to distinguish the case where the same property name is required for more than one interface. Possibly the following clarifies this?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    String MyProperty { get; }
}

public interface IMyInterface2
{
    String MyProperty { get; }
}

// Implement BOTH interfaces explicitly
public class MyClass : IMyInterface, IMyInterface2
{
    string IMyInterface.MyProperty
    {
        get { return "I am Interface1.MyProperty"; }
    }
    string IMyInterface2.MyProperty
    {
        get { return "I am Interface2.MyProperty"; }
    }
    // Same Property Name on the class itself
    public String MyProperty
    {
        get { return "I am a brand new Property!"; }
    }
}

  // Which can be used like so:
  var myClass = new MyClass();
  Console.WriteLine(((IMyInterface)myClass).MyProperty);
  Console.WriteLine(((IMyInterface2)myClass).MyProperty);
  Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyProperty);


'I am Interface1.MyProperty'
'I am Interface2.MyProperty'
'I am a brand new Property!'


// Implement BOTH interfaces - just the one explicitly
public class MyClass : IMyInterface, IMyInterface2
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return "I am Interface1.MyProperty, exposed publicly"; }
    }
    string IMyInterface2.MyProperty
    {
        get { return "I am Interface2.MyProperty"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that. But does the implementing class not have to declare them as public?

Sorry if this sounds retarded I jump between Java and C# a lot and in the Java world you don't put and access modifier on the interface but you do on the implementing method (No properties in Java)

Comment: In implicit implementation - like your first example - you need to mark this property as public. In explicit implementation - no, you cannot mark them as public, they will only be accessible through variables of type `IMyInterface`