# Members not available when implementing IList

Tags: c#

I've tried to create a simple class implementing IList.  However the members are not available unless I first cast DiskBackedCollection to IList.  How can I make it usable without casting?

```
public partial class DiskBackedCollection<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> _underlyingList = new List<T>();

    int IList<T>.IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _underlyingList.IndexOf(item);
    }

    T IList<T>.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _underlyingList[index];
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    int ICollection<T>.Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _underlyingList.Count;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new DiskBackedCollectionEnumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new DiskBackedCollectionEnumerator(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation).

Comment: And I managed to get into my head it was just a code clarity thing! - Thanks for the link.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but it will usually simplify your code to use the base class `Collection<T>`, which has virtual methods `InsertItem`, `RemoveItem` etc that you can override for any custom functionality.

Comment: @Joe To my knowledge the Collection<T> class uses an internal List<T> to store the items.  So the class is best used for adding validation to a simple list.  However as I'm going to be storing and retrieving the data from disk (many millions of rows), I don't want it to be stored in a list internally.  From my implementation above you are correct, but it is far from complete.

Comment: @Lee, you're right, except that to be pedantic, it uses an internal `IList<T>`, which doesn't have to be a `List<T>`.  My comment was based on your implementation above (_underlyingList).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because each of the members has `IList<T>.` in front of them. Remove that and they should show up.

Implementating the interface members with an `IList<T>.` in front of them is called [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: @DaveShaw The compiler should complain if you don’t publicly implement an interface (in which case you technically wouldn’t have implemented it).

Answer (score 0):

Your methods that implement interface requirements must be public.  Yours are not.

Also, you need to remove your explicit implementation:

```
public int Count
{
  get
  {
    return _underlyingList.Count;
  }
}
```