# Cannot Call Implemented Functions of Interface (The Name Does Not Exist In the Current Context)

Tags: c#, oop

I have a public interface that has two methods:

```
public interface IClickStrategy : IStrategy
{
        void InsertSending(MailingResult sending, string connectionString, string tableName);
        void InsertClick(ClickResult click, MailingResult mailing, int campaignId, string              connectionString, string tableName);
}
```

And I have a class that implements this interface functions. So when I implement these functions, they are correctly in place but of course they are not public:

```
void IClickStrategy.InsertSending(MailingResult sending, string connectionString, string tableName){
...
}
```

I'm trying to call this function from my class and it gives me an error that actually makes sense:

> "The name 'InsertSending' does not exist in the current context."

What I want to know is how to use these functions inside my class?
What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: You implemented the method of the interface explicitly.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx). You don't *have* to do that. You could just write:

```
public void InsertSending(...)
{
    ...
}
```

and call the method normally elsewhere. If you *want* to use explicit interface implementation though, you can only call the method via a reference of the interface type, not your class type. So you can use:

```
IClickStrategy strategy = this;
strategy.InsertSending(...);
```

Personally I try not to use explicit interface implementation unless I have a really good reason for doing so - it tends to make things more complicated in my experience, with this just being one example of that.

Comment: I was just about to ask you why there is explicit interface implementation until you replied yourself. Correct answer indeed, sir. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Some food for thought - click me for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"Explicit interface member implementations serve two primary purposes:

Because explicit interface member implementations are not accessible through class or struct instances, they allow interface implementations to be excluded from the public interface of a class or struct. This is particularly useful when a class or struct implements an internal interface that is of no interest to a consumer of that class or struct.

Explicit interface member implementations allow disambiguation of interface members with the same signature. Without explicit interface member implementations it would be impossible for a class or struct to have different implementations of interface members with the same signature and return type, as would it be impossible for a class or struct to have any implementation at all of interface members with the same signature but with different return types.
"

Answer (score 1):

It must be

```
public void InsertSending(MailingResult sending, string connectionString, string tableName){
...
}
```

inside a class, that is decorated as implementing this interface.