# Implementing an interface

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

I'm confused about the implementation of interfaces.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx) `ICollection<T>` has the property `IsReadOnly`

-And-

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) `Collection<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`

-So-

I thought that `Collection<T>` would have the property `IsReadOnly`.

-However-

```
Collection<string> testCollection = new Collection<string>();
Console.WriteLine(testCollection.IsReadOnly);
```

The above code gives the compiler error:

`'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'IsReadOnly' and no extension method 'IsReadOnly' accepting a first argument of type`

`'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

-While-

```
Collection<string> testInterface = new Collection<string>();
Console.WriteLine(((ICollection<string>)testInterface).IsReadOnly);
```

The above code works.

-Question-

I thought classes implementing interfaces had to implement every property, so why doesn't `testCollection` have the `IsReadOnly` property unless you cast it as `ICollection<string>`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation?rq=1 for a better explaination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces can be implemented in couple of ways. Explicitly and implicitly.

**Explicit Implementation:** When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface

**Implicit Implementation:** These can be accessed the interface methods and properties as if they were part of the class.

`IsReadonly` property is implemented explicitly therefore it is not accessible via class directly. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Example:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void SomeMethod();
    void SomeMethod2();
}

public ITest : ITest
{

    void ITest.SomeMethod() {} //explicit implentation
    public void SomeMethod2(){} //implicity implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. After searching for this I found a very thorough explanation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx

Comment: @jemartin80 glad it helped. i was trying to find out a very detailed description of this by Eric Lippert. But i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10):

It is probably implementing the property *explicitly*.

C# enables you to define methods as "explicitly implemented interface methods/properties" which are only visible if you have a reference of the exact interface. This enables you to provide a "cleaner" API, without so much noise.