# Call interface method from an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a class for the purpose of URL rewriting below is the code public class:

```
URLReWriter : IHttpModule
{
    private HttpApplication httpApp = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Init Method implementation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        httpApp = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose Method implementation
    /// </summary>
    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

In the `Init` function we are raising an event to call a function `context.BeginRequest` and implementing the interface `IHttpModule`.

I am implementing the interface `IHttpModule`, it has two methods `Init` and `Dispose`. Now I have `aspx` page and trying to call the `Init` function from `URKReWriter` class like this:

```
EnergyQuote.Framework.Utilities.URLReWriter obj
    = new EnergyQuote.Framework.Utilities.URLReWriter();
```

but it's not possible. Can we call the `Init` function from the `aspx` page?

Comment: This is a HTTPModule, it should be installed into the ASP.Net pipeline and not called by your aspx

Answer (score 1):

The way you have implemented the interface ([Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)) in the class you need to cast the object to the interface to be able to call the functions:

```
var obj = (IHttpModule)new EnergyQuote.Framework.Utilities.URLReWriter(); 
obj.Init(context);
```