# VBA Interfaces and Polymorphism

Tags: vba, interface

I am experimenting with VBA's Interfaces, and I'm a bit annoyed. Most of what I've read on the topic suggests using Interfaces as a means to achieve polymorphism, which seems to work in some of my use cases. Unfortunately, I have run into an issue.

I created a class module to define my interface `iCanvasObject`

I then created a class `cTable` that implements all methods in `iCanvasObject`. So far so good, everything works as expected.

The issue occurs when I define a method specific to `cTable`, and not part of `iCanvasObject`. Even if its `Public` I can't seem to access it from a variable dimensioned as `iCanvasObject`, but instantiated as `cTable`.

```
Dim tbl As iCanvasObject
Set tbl = New cTable
```

Its not visible in IntelliSense which I could live with, but when I try to simply call the method directly, VBA complains of a `Method or data member not found` error. Even though this variable is definitely of type `cTable`

Is there a way for me to create methods specific to `cTable` that I can call while still utilizing the polymorphism benefits of the interface? Said another way, if I dimension a variable as `iCanvasObject`, am I strictly limited to whats defined in this interface?

Comment: What you are thinking about is implementing an interface implicitly, [like in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/143405/11683). VB only has explicit implementation. You'll have to have two variables of different types that view different parts of the object. Or type the variable as `Object` and use late binding (no IntelliSense but works).

Comment: Is it possible to create a second variable of type iCanvasObject and simply reference the original cTable object?

Comment: that is an example of Casting (implicit), VBA is not a very powerful language.

Comment: You will never be able to access methods specific to cTable from a variable declared as ICanvasObject. You can do it the other way round: like `aRealCTableVariable.ICanvasObject_SomeInterfaceMethod`

Comment: I suppose I should be naughty and point out you can 'cheat' and declare `myCanvasObject As Variant` then you can do whatever you like - but you lose type safety and defeat the point of an interface.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but a class can implement two interfaces.

Comment: @PatrickDonovan Yes, it is possible and that is what I was talking about. This [has been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23663714/11683) already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the way polymorphism works.  If you declare it as `iCanvasObject` then that is what it is, and thus, it doesn't have any of the members of `ctable` that don't come from `iCanvasObject`, unless you cast it as a `cTable`.

This has nothing to do with the fact that you're using VBA.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, if you want access to methods that are not part of the interface you have 2 options:

```
Dim tbl As cTable
```

or Cast:

```
Dim tbl As iCanvasObject
Set tbl = New cTable

Dim tbl_i As CTable = DirectCast(tbl, cTable)
```

But I'm not sure VBA supports casting so option #1 is probably better.

Comment: Ok. Well let me ask you this. If i Dim the variable as cTable, and pass it to another method with a signature requiring iCanvasObject, would it determine that cTable implements the interface and is thus acceptable as an argument?

Comment: you will need to declare tbl as cTable not JUST do a `New cTable`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the cTable methods and properties, you will need to "cast" it back to a cTable temporarily.  You can do this as follows:

```
Dim tbl As iCanvasObject
Set tbl = New cTable

'Access iCanvasObject methods/properties through tbl

Dim tempTable As cTable
Set tempTable = tbl 'Implicitly casts tbl to a cTable because tempTable is an object reference to a cTable.

'Access cTable methods/properties through tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cast.  The good news is that classes can implement multiple interfaces.

What I typically do in this situation is I include in my class definition an asSomeInterface method that returns an instance of the class as whatever interface the class is implementing.

Additionally, it should be noted that you can cast from one interface type to another, and VBA will allow this as long as the instantiated object implements both.