# C# method implementation with dot notation

Tags: c#, syntax

Reading an [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727) I came across the following C# syntax in method name.

```
private class sortYearAscendingHelper : IComparer
{
   int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

I understand `Compare` method is method of `IComparer` interface, but coming from `C++` I am not certain what this syntax means. If Compare is part of interface, I would expect to mention that only like `int Compare(...)`. Why we have to specify class?

Comment: This is known as an explicit interface implementation and it is not necessary in this case. You can use an an explicit interface implementation to differentiate a method that belongs to the implicit type/class interface and the *explicit* implemented interface.

Comment: As pointed out by @TimCoker, the question here is "What is this notation" and not "What is Explicit implementation" and perhaps should be reopened.

Comment: @Vache The other post answers this question, which is a suitable reason to close it as a duplicate.  That this question didn't know what to call it, and therefore didn't find *the duplicate question* doesn't make the questions not duplicates.

Comment: Since the linking comment is no longer here, this question should be re-closed as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is an **explicit interface implementation** You use it when you derive from multiple interfaces that contain similar (same signature) functions but need different implementations for each interface.

More information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

(Sample from linked page):

> If the two interface members do not perform the same function,
>   however, this can lead to an incorrect implementation of one or both
>   of the interfaces. It is possible to implement an interface member
>   explicitly—creating a class member that is only called through the
>   interface, and is specific to that interface. This is accomplished by
>   naming the class member with the name of the interface and a period.
>   For example:

```
public class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    void IControl.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
    }
    void ISurface.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ISurface.Paint");
    }
}
```

> The class member IControl.Paint is only available through the IControl
>   interface, and ISurface.Paint is only available through ISurface. Both
>   method implementations are separate, and neither is available directly
>   on the class.

Comment: This is a fine answer but what is the point? The question is a duplicate.

Comment: @ByteBlast I didn't know it was a duplicate when I answered. Given that this question is about the syntax (not explicitly about implicit vs. explicit implementations) I'm not sure I agree that it *is* a duplicate.

Comment: Let it be known that I do not mean any offence, I am only trying to understand the mindset behind answers in these scenarios because they always leave me with a o_O face.

Comment: @ByteBlast no offence taken :).