# c# interface public private

Tags: c#, interface

Can someone explain how an intereface can be forced to be implemented as private or public. Usually when I define an interface, every method/property are public. In the example, using "IEnumerable" produce a public method "GetEnumerator()" but using the interface "IEnumerable" the method "IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()" is private by default.

```
public class customEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: All methods defined in an interface are public, because an interface defines a public contract. Private methods are an implementation detail, so they have no place in an interface.

Comment: `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is not at all private, it can be accessed only via interface instance, that is the difference

Comment: the public method way of implementing the interface is called Implicit implementaion and `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` way of implementing is called Explicit implementation. Refer the link mentioned by Iridium for more clarity

Comment: Visual Studio create the above code using the "implement interface" option. I can see in the related question that using the "explicit" option it won´t populate the methods as public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A private member makes no sense as part of an interface as all methods defined in an interface are public. An interface is there to define a set of methods, a role, an object must always implement.

Private methods are just the implementation details and they are not intended for public consumption.

As per MSDN

> The CLR also allows an interface to contain static methods, static
>   fields, constants, and static constructors. However, a CLS-compliant
>   interface must not have any of these static members because some
>   programming languages aren’t able to define or access them. In fact,
>   C# prevents an interface from defining any static members. In
>   addition, the CLR doesn’t allow an interface to contain any instance
>   fields or instance constructors.

For more details you may refer this:- [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)