# Differences in Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm learning WPF and still trying to fully understand the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I found the following example:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
    }   
}
```

The example follows the same format that I see often in other code. In Visual Studio 2013, I have the option of allowing the IDE to implement the interface for me explicitly. Doing so creates the following:

```
   event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
   {
       add { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
       remove { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
   }
```

How are these two different? If I decided to use the code generated by Visual Studio, how would that look compared to the first example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, I don't think he understands the fundamentals of events. Not just the Implicit/Explicit implementaitons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really two questions here.  First, what's with the add and remove in an event and second, what is an explicit interface implementation?  These are orthogonal things.

#### Events with add and remove

In C#, events are actually a lot like properties.  An event has an `add` method and a `remove` method.  If you don't specify them explicitly, the compiler will create them for you as well as a delegate field to back the event (which you can access from within your own class by referring to the event).

You can create the `add` and `remove` methods yourself if you wish (and if you want to implement the interface explicitly, you *must*).  In that case you usually also create a delegate field to back your event:

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent
{
    add { mSomeEvent += value; }
    remove { mSomeEvent -= value; }
}

private void RaiseSomeEvent()
{
    var handler = mSomeEvent;
    if( handler != null ) handler( this, EventArgs.Empty );
}

private EventHandler mSomeEvent;
```

Notice that if you want to raise the event you have to refer to the backing field.  You can no longer do it using the event name itself.  You could actually do this for `INotifyPropertyChange` without resorting to an explicit implementation.

#### Explicit Interface Implementation

When you implement an interface explicitly you actually create "private" versions of the interface members.  Now, I put private in quotes because the implementation is not actually private.  The implementation is only accessible if the cast is accessed from the interface type.  That's a bit of a mouthful, so here's an example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar { get; }
}

public class A : IFoo
{
    int IFoo.Bar
    {
        get { return -1; }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say we have the following in a method somewhere:

```
var a = new A();
int bar = a.Bar;
```

This will generate a compile error, because the type `A` doesn't have a publically visible member called `Bar`.  However, if we cast to `IFoo` first:

```
var a = new A();
int bar = ((IFoo) a).Bar;
```

Now it compiles and when it runs, `bar == -1`.  You could also have strongly typed the variable `a` as `IFoo` as well:

```
IFoo a = new A();
int bar = a.Bar;
```

That would also work.  So this member can be accessed from outside the class (and even outside the assembly), but *only* directly through the declaring interface type.  This can be useful to hide implementation you don't want to support (like the mutable parts of `IList<T>`) or if you have different implementations depending on the interface, like `GetEnumerator()` in `IEnumerable` as opposed to the `GetEnumerator()` in `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public class B : IFoo
{
    public int Bar { get { return 2; } }
    int IFoo.Bar { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Now if we use this class like so:

```
B b = new B();
IFoo bAsIFoo = b;
int barFromB = b.Bar;
int barFromFoo = bAsIFoo.Bar;
```

What you'll get here is `barFromB == 2` and `barFromFoo == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading up on Event and EventHandlers in .NET.

Lets call this A

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

and this B

```
event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
{
    add { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    remove { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Are similar, but there are differences.

1. A `PropertyChanged` is explicitly (you have specified the access modifier for it) public where as B `PropertyChanged` is implicitly public as you are providing an implementation for a public Interface.
2. A `PropertyChanged` implements the default `add/remove`, which are just wrappers to `PropertyChanged += handler` and `ProeprtyChanged -= handler` where as B `PropertyChanged` implements `add/remove` as `throw new exception`. Therefore if anything was to try and subscribe to the B 'PropertyChanged' event, it will throw the `NotImplementedException`.
3. A `PropertyChanged` event will be accesible to anyone using your class, or your class as `INotifyPropertyChanged`, where as B `PropertyChanged` event will **ONLY** be accessible once someone casts your class to `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Now your other piece of code:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
    }   
}
```

Is used to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event(if not null), and notify any subscribers that the giver `propertyName` has changed. You need whenever you want to invoke events on your class from external code, as events can **ONLY** be invoked from within your class.

Comment: Explicit implementations are not internal.  They are accessible publically but only directly through the declaring interface type.  That restriction is true even for the implementing class itself (so the member can't be accessed even from within the same class; you can get around this by casting `this` to the declaring interface type).

Comment: @Kyle +1 thanks for pointing, don't know what I was thinking!