# Abstract class using IComparer

Tags: c#, compare, abstract-class, icomparer

I want to create and abstract class A that implements IComparer so that I can implement different forms of comparing in the subclasses and later on do:

```
A sortBy = new B();
A sortBy2 = new C();
```

I'm new in C# and I don't quite get how to do that. I want them to implement this variations of this method:

```
int IComparer<Flower>.Compare(Flower a, Flower b)
        {
            if (a.leaves > b.leaves)
                return 1;
            if (a.leaves< b.leaves)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
```

But I can't use abstract or override on it because it won't compile.
Could you give me an idea of how to implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with current code `IComparer<Flower>` is implemented explicitly ([SO: implicit vs explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation))

implement it implicitly to make `abstract` or `virtual`:

```
public abstract class A: IComparer<Flower>
{           
    public abstract int Compare(Flower a, Flower b);
}
```

OR

```
public abstract class A: IComparer<Flower>
{           
    public virtual int Compare(Flower a, Flower b)
    {
        if (a.leaves > b.leaves)
            return 1;
        if (a.leaves< b.leaves)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with your second option doing this: `List<Flower> flowers = new List<Flowers>(); A sorting = new A();  flowers.Sort(sorting);` but it won't compile, it says the last line has invalid arguments

Comment: @moondaisy, if `A` is abstract, it is not allowed to create A object `A sorting = new A();`. But if `B` is inherited from `A` and non-abstract, this shoud work: `A sorting = new B();`; or just make A non-abstract

Comment: By bad, I was doing `A sorting = new B()` and it still won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, I wasn't casting sorting as an `IComparer<Flower>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
abstract class Flower : IComparer<Flower>
{
    public int Leaves { get; set; }

    public int Compare(Flower x, Flower y)
    {
        if (x.Leaves > y.Leaves)
            return 1;
        if (x.Leaves < y.Leaves)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Abstract classes are closely related to interfaces. They are classes
>   that cannot be instantiated, and **are frequently either partially**
>   **implemented**, or not at all implemented. One key difference between
>   abstract classes and interfaces is that a class may implement an
>   unlimited number of interfaces, but may inherit from only one abstract
>   (or any other kind of) class. A class that is derived from an abstract
>   class may still implement interfaces. Abstract classes are useful when
>   creating components because they allow you specify an invariant level
>   of functionality in some methods, but leave the implementation of
>   other methods until a specific implementation of that class is needed.
>   They also version well, because if additional functionality is needed
>   in derived classes, it can be added to the base class without breaking
>   code.

The key of the above definition is the text that is bold. Since you want classes that has as a base class the `Flower` class to be compared, this class, `Flower` has to implement the `IComparer<Flower>` interface.