# How to make some methods "exclipit" and some "implicit", just like what we see when implementing from IEnumerable <out T>？

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If you write a class and make it implement `IEnumerable<out T>`, you will find one method is implicit, while the other is an explicit. But our own interfaces cannot do that, so how to make our own interfaces (some methods are implicit and some explicit?)

---

The detailled steps are:

1) Create a class.

2) Make the class implement from "IEnumerable".

3) Choose "Implicit From the interface".

For step 3, you will find that two methods are generated:

[image]

I wonder to know:

1) Why when I choose choice 1, one method is implicit while the other is exclipit?

2) What can I do to make the Vs's intellisens act the same result, what kinds of interfaces can I define? Can you give me some samples?

Regurads!

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable` meaning that every class implementing `IEnumerable<T>` has to implement two methods with the same signature `GetEnumerator()`. The only way you can do that is by explicitly implementing one of them - `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @chomba: I know the reason, but What I want to know is:  How can I define an interface with some methods, and another class implements it, some methods are implicit, while the others are exclipit (I mean just Vs will insense me, just like what actions from IEnumerable <out T>)?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to make the Vs's intellisens act the same result, what
>   kinds of interfaces can I define? Can you give me some samples?

Let's say you have these two interfaces:

```
public interface IContainer<out T> : IContainer
{
    new T Value { get; }
}

public interface IContainer
{
    object Value { get; }
}
```

Let's now define a `StringContainer` class that implements `IContainer<string>`:

```
public class StringContainer : IContainer<string> { }
```

If you hover over `IContainer<string>` you should see the same *tooltip* that shows up when implementing `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you click the first option - *Implement Interface*, Visual Studio will realize that it can't implicitly implement both members(`IContainer.Value` and `IContainer<string>.Value`) because they have the same *signature*.

So, *VS* will  implicitly implement the member declared in the interface being implemented (that is `IContainer<string>.Value`) and will explicitly implement the inherited interface member `IEnumerable.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

All interface method implementations can be implemented explicitly or implicitly (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)).

The reason `IEnumerable<out T>` needs the `GetEnumerator` method to be explicitly implemented is that `IEnumerable<out T>` derives from `IEnumerable` and both interfaces have different same named methods.