# Class with public access specifier is not able to access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two class library named `HTS.lib.Common` and `HTS.lib.Common.Contract`

In `HTS.lib.Common.Contract` i have ModelView class and Interfaces

In `HTS.lib.Common` i have public classes which inherit some interfaces from `HTS.lib.Common.Contract` and have definition for it and all are of public type.

I have a MVC application which have reference of above two projects i can able to access only `HTS.lib.Common.Contract` members and not `HTS.lib.Common`

I am wondering how can it can be happen, in my controller class i can able to create instance through DependencyResolver of `HTS.lib.Common.Contract`. But when i try to access `HTS.lib.Common` members not at all :(

Can any one know how we can configure so that derived class can`t be accessible but base interface and class able to access.

Comment: No error, just i am trying to understand the logic behind it, why i can't able to access even though i have reference of  'HTS.lib.Common'

Comment: If you have an actual question, then ask it.  Otherwise you will be down voted and closed.

Comment: @whoami - no error? How do you know that you are "able to access ... not 'HTS.lib.Common'"?

Comment: @JK, I hope through this form we can able to gain, or develop knowledge. With out understanding my nature of question i am wondering your way of response.

Comment: @lgor21: As i said in my initial post i can able to access my 'HTS.lib.Common' through 'HTS.lib.Common.Contract'. I am creating instance for 'HTS.lib.Common.Contract' with help of 'DependencyResolver', so that i can able to access ''HTS.lib.Common' class and member. But i can't able to access my classes in 'HTS.lib.Common' directly.

Comment: @whoami - How are you accessing classes "in 'HTS.lib.Common' directly" and how do you know that you cannot?

Comment: I tried creating new instance for the class 'MyAccount' using 'HTS.lib.Common' but i can't able to access. The When i put dot after 'HTS.lib.Common' only i can able to see 'Contract' namespace in the popup and no other class shown which under 'HTS.lib.Common'.

Comment: can u show some code to put more light on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably implemented the interface in your common library explicitly, that'll mean all your methods are private and can only be accessed via the interface. As an example, given this interface:

```
public interface IUser
{
    String Username { get; }
}
```

You can implement that interface in two ways, firstly explicitly:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    String IUser.Username
    {
        get { return "Bob"; }
    }
}
```

In the above example you can only access the Username property via the interface, like this:

```
IUser user = new User();
var name = user.Username;
```

If you create the class directly you won't be able to access that property:

```
User user = new User();
var name = user.Username; //won't compile
```

If you want to be able to access the property in both ways you simply implement the interface "implicitly":

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public String Username
    {
        get { return "Bob"; }
    }
}
```

Now both of the forms of access shown above will work.

As to whether you *should* implement interfaces explicitly or implicitly, it depends, there are other questions on here that discuss that if you're interested.

Comment: Check out this question for a discussion of explicit vs implicit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation