# Explicitly set an internal property from an inherited interface C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a scenario. I am trying to wrap my code up so that I have generic entities which instantiate themselves according to the realm that they are in.

Like an onion which only has a layer which it deals with itself but at the same time allowing somebody from a higher level to trigger the internal layers to start doing something. It allows me to package my components in a nicer and more reusable manner since i will be able to implement code which propagates safely to all required modules without affecting higher levels which may be deriving from the same base classes. So basically there will be a hierarchy of levels which classes will share commonality.

In short, I have a property of type interface(IBar) inside an interface(IFoo) which is inheriting another interface(IFooBase), and i have another property inside this base interface which is the same name of the property from interface above of a type which is a base interface of its original(IBarBase)

My problem is my implementation of Foo, which calls a method from FooBase which accesses property of IBar cannot access IBarBase because the object is not instantiated, the reason being that inherited interfaces of the same time performs hiding of properties instead of overwriting.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated on how i can go about assigning IBarBase with an instantiated object of Bar (of which is actually an implementation of IBar and derived from IBarBase) so that i may be able to access the property from a lower level to perform some task.

Sorry is this sounding too complex? im not sure if i am making any sense, the code before is for reference. And a picture also for illustration

[image]

```
public interface IFoo : IFooBase
{
    new IBar inst { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooBase
{
    IBarBase inst { get; set; }
    void SetEventHandlers();
}

public interface IBar : IBarBase
{
    int stuff { get; set; }
}

public interface IBarBase
{
    int otherStuff { get; set;}
}

public class Foo : FooBase, IFoo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        inst = new Bar();
        SetEventHandler();
    }

    public new IBar inst { get; set; }
}

public class FooBase : IFooBase
{
    public void SetEventHandler()
    {
        inst.otherStuff = 123;
    }

    public IBarBase inst { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : BarBase, IBar
{
    public int stuff { get; set; }
}

public class BarBase : 
{
    public int otherStuff { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you point us to the line in your code that goes wrong? I have a hard time understanding your design and problem.

Comment: when Foo calls SetEventHandler() in the constructor. Even though i have instantiated inst, inst appears as null when i try to assign inst.otherstuff = 123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have another variable `inst` which you have created in `Foo` (note the `new` keyword):

```
public new IBar inst { get; set; }
```

It hides the other `inst` you have in your base class. So you are not setting `FooBase.inst` in `Foo`, you are setting `Foo.inst`. Hence, `FooBase.inst` is null.

You could explictly implement the interface member:

```
public class Foo : FooBase, IFoo
{
    IBar IFoo.inst { get { return instAsIBar; } set { instAsIBar = value; } }

    public IBar instAsIBar { get { return (IBar)this.inst; } set { this.inst = value; } }
}
```

Comment: definately agreed, but my question is how can i set Foo.inst and FooBase.inst together. Because i know Foo,inst is actually a type derived from the type of FooBase,inst so actually i want them both to be linked together.

Comment: I think it is almost correct, but the set is setting directly as the type of the internal IBarBase. Now i cant access any of the properties defined in IBar. How do i also set the properties of both simultaneously?

Comment: You mean like `instAsIBar` in my updated code? Setting the one property does also set the other one, since it just encapsulates the other.

Comment: Yes this works i think, but i would have to change all references to be from instAsIBar in order to access the properties of IBar. Is it possible to use the same name ie inst?

Comment: Not really. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. Thank you so much anyway. You are a champion. Just one more small question. What this means is that, when i will need to access IBar stuff from inst, i will have to cast it explicitly as IBar first before being able to do anything. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [an explicit implementation of the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation) rather than overriding the `inst`property:

```
public class Foo : FooBase, IFoo
{
   public Foo() 
   {
        inst = new Bar();
        SetEventHandlers();
   }

   IBar IFoo.inst { get; set; }
}
```

Then this test passes:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TC 
{
    [Test]
    public void t() 
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        ((FooBase)f).inst.otherStuff.Should().Be(123);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got to give it to Patrick as his answer is more complete. Thanks anyway