# .net framework List<T> inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-inheritance

MS source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef)

In .net `List<T>` class inherit two interface
(`IList<T>` and `System.Collections.IList`)

And it implement two method add method

```
public void Add(T item) {
        if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
        _items[_size++] = item;
        _version++;
    }

int System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
    {
        ThrowHelper.IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<T>(item, ExceptionArgument.item);


        try { 
            Add((T) item);            
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongValueTypeArgumentException(item, typeof(T));            
        }

        return Count - 1;
    }
```

first method is public, second is private method.

IList have no add method, but System.Collections.IList did

What is the concept of inherit from System.Collections.IList?

Comment: Just to be clear, classes implement interfaces and inherit from base classes. Classes do not inherit interfaces. (Interfaces can inherit from base interfaces though).

Comment: `List<T>` does not *inherit* from `IList<T>` and `IList`, it *implements* them, because they are interfaces, not classes. You can implement as many interfaces as you like - this is not "multiple inheritance".

Comment: The second is not a private, it is just an explicit implementation of the System.Collections.IList.Add method

Comment: "What is the concept of inherit from `System.Collections.IList`?" - It is so that `List<T>` may be used in any place that a type of `System.Collections.IList` is required - this is particularly important when working with non-generics code. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others have already pointed out, classes implement interfaces not inherit them.

```
int System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
```

Here the class is explicitly implementing the Add() method of the interface. Contrary to implicit interface implementation, such methods can are accessible only using a interface reference not the class reference. Refer here for detailed difference between implicit and explicit interface implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)