# How to restrict the interface implementation in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface

Is it possible to permit only some specific classes to implement an iterface?

For Exmaple:

In `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` class has `KeyCollection` sealed class with implemented `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TKey>` as well `System.Collections.ICollection` but when I look at code Visual Studio builds from metadata it shows that `KeyCollection` implements only `System.Collections.ICollection` interface methods.

How to restrict same?

[image]

Simple example:
I have used the same interfaces but i have faced the compilation issue.

[image]

Comment: How is that an example of what you're asking for, if anyone can implement `ICollection` or `ICollection<TKey>`?

Comment: If you want restrict implementation of interface - move interface in the own assembly(project), make interface `internal`, in the same assembly  implement interface in the public classes, which you will use in your other projects

Comment: No you can't, how one can restrict class from not implementing any interface implemented on it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Most likely you keeping some use-case in mind.

Comment: In above case ICollection<TKey> and ICollection interfaces are used but ICollection interface only implemented how is it possible?

Comment: @yoganathank implicit vs. explicit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation ? (Clearly it has nothing to do with what you are *asking* in the post... also it may be what you *actually interested in*).

Comment: Also please confirm that my edit of the post is inline with what you see (in particular that you've used VS autogenerated code from metadata to capture picture)

Answer (score 0):

That is true but `KeyCollection` hasn't any restriction. `KeyCollection` seems to be using `ICollection` and `ICollection<TKey>` methods. Actually, it implements all methods. Beacuse `ICollection<TKey>` and `ICollection` implement `IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable` interfaces.

`ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable`

`ICollection : IEnumerable`