# ContractInvariant method for interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, code-contracts

I am new to contracts I went through documentation of msdn for code contracts

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx

I picked the idea of Contract Invariants. However when I add the Invariant method It does not access fields form interface.

```
[ContractClass(typeof(Account_Contract))]
public interface IAccount
{
    int AccountID { get; }

    string AccountOwner { get; }

    int GetAccountID(); // Our 'internal'unique identifier for this account
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IAccount))]
internal abstract class Account_Contract : IAccount
{
    int IAccount.AccountID
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
            return default(int);
        }
    }

    string IAccount.AccountOwner
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));
            return default(string);
        }
    }

    int IAccount.GetAccountID()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
        return default(int);
    }
}
```

It works fine but if I add

```
Contracts.Requires(AccountID > 0);
```

VS does not access it. I have also tried

```
Contracts.Requires(this.AccountID > 0);
Contracts.Requires(IAccount.AccountID > 0);
```

None working. What is that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where and what is your problem? did you try this `Contracts.Requires(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);`?

Comment: I want make one certain member of IAccount as invariant. 
Like,
Contract.Invariant(IAccount.AccountID > 0);

Comment: But It does not access AccountID from IAccount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using explicit implementation of the interface which means that if you want to treat the object as a member of that interface then you need to cast to that first.

So when you want to access `AccountID` on a instance named `myInstance` you would need to write `((IAccount)myInstance).AccountId`. If you try to access `AccountId` directly on the class then it will not be recognised.

What this means is that if you need to reference it from within the class for your contracts you should be using `((IAccount)this).AccountId`.

The easier way of dealing with this though is to implement the interface implicitly instead and things will be a bit more natural all the way through. To implicitly implement the interface just remove the `IAccount.` from the beginning of their declarations. For more on implicit and explicit interfaces see [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation) .

Comment: I think his problem is that props are not public, tecnically the interface is not implemented.

Comment: And also you are right, he is using explicit declaration when he should be using implicit way.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca: An explicitly implemented interface is by definition public. And in fact one step further it is actually not allowed to put the public modifier on an explicitly implemented member.

Comment: You are correct I figured that out myself later. Implementation has to be explicit as am doing it for code contracts.

Comment: @UsamaAslam: Cool. I haven't used code contracts much so not sure on the ins and outs of them. Am more solid on interface implementations. Glad you've got it sorted now though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that **you are using explicit declaration** (as @Chris has comment in his answer), so you have to cast `this` as `IAccount`.

I think **you should be using implicit declaration** (commonly used), in that all methods and props implemented by `IAccount` must public.

### Implicit declaration way:

```c#
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IAccount))]
internal abstract class Account_Contract : IAccount
{
    //In order to implement IAccount interface, must be public
    public int AccountID
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Requires(AccountID > 0);
            return default(int);
        }
    }

    //In order to implement IAccount interface, must be public
    public string AccountOwner
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));
            return default(string);
        }
    }

    //In order to implement IAccount interface, must be public
    public int GetAccountID()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
        return default(int);
    }
}

[ContractClass(typeof(Account_Contract))]
public interface IAccount
{
    int AccountID { get; }

    string AccountOwner { get; }

    int GetAccountID();             ////Our 'internal'unique identifier for this account
}
```

**EDIT: I'm including @Cris 's answer here.**

### Explicit declaration way:

```c#
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IAccount))]
internal abstract class Account_Contract : IAccount
{
    int IAccount.AccountID
    {
        get
        {
            //You must cast this as IAccount
            Contract.Requires(((IAccount)this).AccountID > 0);
            return default(int);
        }
    }

    string IAccount.AccountOwner
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));
            return default(string);
        }
    }

    public int GetAccountID()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
        return default(int);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this does not inherit AccountID from IAccount. Also I do not have a problem there. Problem appears when I try to access members of IAccount in Contracts.ensure or Invariants

Comment: @UsamaAslam: This is implementing the AccountID implicitly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation for explanation of the difference between explicit and implicit implementation.

Comment: Take a look, I've edited my answer including all the code

Comment: You're first line is still wrong: "he problem is that your properties are not public, so they are not implemented.". As I commented on my post when it came up explicitly implemented interface members are automatically public and it is actually illegal to put the public keyword on them. So the interface is implemented in a valid way (though maybe not the best way).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to make it consistent