# Interface mapping

Tags: c#, interface

Here at work we mainly used Delphi, but also some C#.
So today a college asked me an interesting question today: How do I perform Intreface mapping in C#? And since I do not know here is the question for you:

First the Delphi Example:

```
unit UnitInterfaceMapping;

interface

type
  IMyFirstInterface = interface(IInterface)
    procedure DoSomethingInteresting;
    procedure DoSomethingElse;
  end;

  IMyNextInterface = interface(IInterface)
    procedure DoSomethingInteresting;
  end;

  TMyCombinedObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyFirstInterface, IMyNextInterface)
  private
    procedure IMyFirstInterface.DoSomethingInteresting = DoSomethingInterestingFirst;
    procedure IMyNextInterface.DoSomethingInteresting = DoSomethingInterestingNext;
  public
    procedure DoSomethingInterestingFirst;
    procedure DoSomethingInterestingNext;
    procedure DoSomethingElse;
  end;

implementation

uses
  VCL.Dialogs;
{ TMyCombinedObject }

procedure TMyCombinedObject.DoSomethingElse;
begin
  ShowMessage('DoSomethingElse');
end;

procedure TMyCombinedObject.DoSomethingInterestingFirst;
begin
  ShowMessage('DoSomethingInterestingFirst');
end;

procedure TMyCombinedObject.DoSomethingInterestingNext;
begin
  ShowMessage('DoSomethingInterestingNext');
end;

end.
```

Form a Form I call my code:

```
uses
  UnitInterfaceMapping;

procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyFirstInterface: IMyFirstInterface;
  MyNextInterface: IMyNextInterface;
begin
  MyFirstInterface := TMyCombinedObject.Create;
  MyFirstInterface.DoSomethingInteresting;
  MyFirstInterface.DoSomethingElse;

  MyNextInterface := TMyCombinedObject.Create;
  MyNextInterface.DoSomethingInteresting;
end;
```

The result is three dialog boxes, one from each method.

Then I tried to port it to C#:

```
using System;

namespace InterfaceMapping
{

    public interface IMyFirstInterface
    {
        void DoSomethingInteresting();
        void DoSomethingElse();
    }


    public interface IMyNextInterface
    {
        void DoSomethingInteresting();
    }

    public class CombinedObject : IMyFirstInterface, IMyNextInterface
    {
        public void DoSomethingInteresting()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMyFirstInterface.DoSomethingElse()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMyFirstInterface.DoSomethingInteresting()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new CombinedObject() <== Problem
        }
    }
}
```

The main point is when creating a new instance of `CombinedObject` I only see the `DoSomethingInteresting` method.

So in short: How do I perform Interface mapping in C#

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/inherit-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: `IMyFirstInterface obj = new CombinedObject();` you would get both methods. The problem here is you have explicit implementation of Interfaces.

Comment: You should have a look at implicit and explicit interface implementations. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation) question might help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access methods from `IMyFirstInterface` interface, you need to explicitly define a type of an object:

```
IMyFirstInterface obj = new CombinedObject();
obj.DoSomethingInteresting(); //Method is accessible
```

Lines above will invoke `void IMyFirstInterface.DoSomethingInteresting()` method, on the other hand, if you instantiate object of type `CombinedObject`:

```
var obj = new CombinedObject();
obj.DoSomethingInteresting();
```

Implicitly implemented interface's method will be invoked: `public void DoSomethingInteresting()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer answer :)

Comment: @JensBorrisholt you welcome :)