# Single Event with different argument type

Tags: c#, events, arguments

I have a class with methods that report the current state of the process. 
I usually use a UIHandle.Writline where UIHandle is an interface with 2 methods.

```
UIHandle.WritLine(string StringInput)
```

Or

```
UIHandle.WritLine(List<string> StringInput)
```

Which is used this way:

```
UIHandle.WriteLine("Checking for error...");
UIHandle.WriteLine(CheckForMissing(newCollection)); //Where CheckForMissing returns a list of strings
```

I was wondering if there is a possibility that I was not aware of to trigger the methods through an event rather than the class such as:

```
TriggerTheResponseEvent("Checking for error...");
TriggerTheResponseEvent(CheckForMissing(newCollection));
```

I though it would be better to avoid interface as I currently use. And I could add a log file more easily...

Comment: *"to trigger the methods through an event rather than the class"* - can you explain this? You don't like prefixing interface for [explicitly implemented interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143405/1997232) methods or what? What events have to do with it? Or are those simple static methods?

Comment: I am using interface right now, it obviously works fine. I was just wondering if it there was a way to pass different argument type to events without using object.