# Why typecast StreamReader object into IDisposable interface?

Tags: c#

The following:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText ("file.txt"))
{
 ...
}
```

is precisely equivalent to:

```
{
 StreamReader reader = File.OpenText ("file.txt");
 try
 {
 ...
 }
 finally
 {
 if (reader != null)
 ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
 }
}
```

My question is, did we explicitly typecast StreamReader object into IDisposable interface? Can one cast class types into interfaces? I don't understand what we gained from typecasting to interface since there is no implementation there. Code example is from the book I am reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is precisely equivalent to:

It's not, actually. What actually happens can't be represented in C#.

However, imagine this case:

```
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class implementation");
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit implementation");
    }
}
```

If you write `using (new MyDisposable()) { }`, then it will print "Explicit implementation".

That is, a `using` statement will call the actual implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose`. Calling `MyDisposable.Dispose()` will however print "Class implementation".

This is what the cast `((IDisposable)reader).Dispose()` is showing -- this equivalent C# code is calling the `Dispose` method which implements `IDisposable.Dispose()`.

---

**However**, if the disposable object is a struct, then the C# code `((IDisposable)mystruct).Dispose()` will box it. A `using` statement will however *not* box structs.

Given:

```
public struct MyDisposableStruct : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class implementation");
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit implementation");
    }
}
```

It is not possible to write C# code to get it to print "Explicit implementation" without also boxing the struct. This however what a `using` statement does.

Comment: Besides ability to implement 2 interfaces that have method names with same signature, what would be a practical reason to explicitly implement interface methods?

Comment: @miran80 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation

Answer (score -3):

it's not necessary,you can do it like this:

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText ("file.txt"))
{
 ...
reader.Dispose();
}
```

it's also can clean the object

Comment: You don't need to call Dispose if you use a `using` statement.