# Problem with Interface Implementation When using Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have created IShallowCloneable interface to create shallow copy of class for All of my class but with inheritance it is not working properly.

Look at Main method, node2 is returning Point3D object Instead of Node.

Details

- Point2D is Base Class
- Point3D Class Derived from Point2D Class
- Node
  Class Derived from Point3D Class

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var node = new Node(1, 0, 0, 0);
                var node2 = node.ShallowClone();//this code is returing Point3D Object instead of Node
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IShallowCloneable<T>
    {
        T ShallowClone();
    }

    public class Point2D : IShallowCloneable<Point2D>
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Point2D()
        {
        }
        public Point2D(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public Point2D ShallowClone()
        {
            return new Point2D(X, Y);
        }
    }
    public class Point3D : Point2D, IShallowCloneable<Point3D>
    {
        public int Z { get; set; }

        public Point3D()
        {
        }
        public Point3D(int x, int y,int z):base(x,y)
        {
            Z = z;
        }
        new public Point3D ShallowClone()
        {
            return new Point3D(X, Y,Z);
        }
    }

    public class Node:Point3D, IShallowCloneable<Node>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Node()
        {

        }
        public Node(int id,int x, int y, int z):base(x,y,z)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        Node IShallowCloneable<Node>.ShallowClone()
        {
            return new Node(Id,X, Y, Z);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for `Node` you've implemented `IShallowCloneable<Node>` as [explicit interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation), so it will work only if you cast to it:

```
// prints Node
Console.WriteLine(((IShallowCloneable<Node>)node).ShallowClone().GetType().Name);
```

If you want it to behave as `Point3D` you need to implement it as you do there ( hiding inherited `Point2D` implementation with [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) keyword).

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to use ShallowClone method Explicitly without changing Class

```
var node = new Node(1, 0, 0, 0);
var node2 = ((IShallowCloneable<Node>)node).ShallowClone();
```

or if you  want implicit implementation you have to Modify ShallowClone() method implementation in Node Class like this

```
new public Node ShallowClone()
{
    return new Node(Id, X, Y, Z);
}
```

Additional Reference

[C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)

Comment: Please explain why this is the answer

Comment: @ColinM Now , my explaination is ok?