# Why not "IEnumerator IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()" while declaring the interface method ? IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

I have 3 questions about `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` interface:

1. Why not `IEnumerator IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()`, since it is the interface method ?
2. Why it could not be public ?
3. Why the returning value Current supposed to be an object, even if I know the specific type ?

the code: (the questions are marked)

```
 public class myIEnumCollection : IEnumerable<int> 
        {
            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() // 1)
            {
                return new myIEnumerator();           
            }

            IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator(){ // 2)  
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public class myIEnumerator: IEnumerator<int> {

            public int Current{get; private set; } = 0;
            object IEnumerator.Current => Current; // 3)

            public bool MoveNext(){ 
                Current++;    
                return true; 
            }
            public void Reset() {
                Current = 0;
            } 

            public void Dispose(){

            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: "And why it doesn't crash ?" - it will (with a `NotImplementedException`) if you end up calling that. You haven't shown how you're using this at all. In general, I'm finding your question hard to understand - partly because you're asking four questions in a single post. Stack Overflow works much better if you ask *one* question per post.

Comment: I am not using it(empty main method). The aim is to get it runnable

Comment: I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think you have your implementations reversed. If you follow the sample code on [`IEnumerable<T>`'s page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0#examples), you would declare it like this:

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
    return new myIEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

2. `IEnumerable<T>` [implements the non-generic interface `IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0#notes-to-implementers) and both define a method `GetEnumerable()` with different return types. Because of this, only one of these methods can be directly accessed (see this question for more information: [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143405))
3. Related to 2, `IEnumerator<T>` [implements the non-generic interface `IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=net-5.0#notes-to-implementers) which defines it as an object.