# C# DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection can't implicitly cast to IList

Tags: c#, oop, datagridview, interface

Observations:

1. `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` implements `IList`, `ICollection`, and `IEnumerable`.
2. `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` does not have all the functions in its API to implement all of these interfaces (e.g. it's missing `IList.Add`

Question:

1. How can `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` not implement all the functions in the interface?
2. Why can't the compiler implicitly cast to the interface (or at least provide details in the compiler message that there's ambiguity)?

Example:
Where `selected` is `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` and `cell` is `DataGridViewCell`

This doesn't compile: `selected.Add(cell);`
But this does: `((IList)selected).Add(cell);`

Sources:
[DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedcellcollection?view=netframework-4.5)

Comment: "DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection does not have all the functions in its API to implement all of these interfaces (e.g. it's missing IList.Add" - [yes it does](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/0bf6f23ab9e7ba59fb62c05dd568e83b37c7c2ac/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection.cs#L22-L25), it's just not public.

Comment: @gunr2171 That's strange, I was always lead to believe that interfaces had to be public since you can't specify the access modifier within an interface. In this case I guess the question is: "Why is it legal to implement an interface function as private?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation)