# Calling an implemented interface method in Main c#

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I am writting a reusuable program, which contains different sorting algorithms. I want each sorting algorithm to implement a "print to console function".So I implemented an interface:

```
namespace ConsoleControl
{
    interface IConsoleControlInterface
    {
        void PrintArray(int[] array)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

then, my BubbleSort class implements that interface:

```
using ConsoleControl;

namespace BubbleSort
{
    public class BubbleSortClass : IConsoleControlInterface
    {
```

as this is an interface, BubbleSortClass has to have an implementation of interface's function PrintArray(int[] array):

```
        void IConsoleControlInterface.PrintArray(int[] array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing The Array");
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }
        }
```

But how do I actually call this method in my Main()?
I tried this:

```
        BubbleSort.BubbleSortClass arrayToBeSorted2 = new BubbleSort.BubbleSortClass(10);
        arrayToBeSorted2.InitializeArray();
        arrayToBeSorted2.PrintArray(arrayToBeSorted2.array);
```

but the compiler show that the PrintArray function does not exist, how to fix it?

I tried calling it from the object arrayToBeSorted2.PrintArray
I assumed that simple call PrintArray(...) would not work as this function is not marked as static

Comment: Please post a runnable code

Comment: I doubt your design. `PrintArray` does not seem to be related to a specific sort algorithm, not even to a sort algorithm at all. So why is in implemented in a sort algorithm class? Looks more like a general utility method.

Comment: This is a general function and I want each of the algorithm to implement it

Comment: How would these implementations differ from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've [explicitly implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) `IConsoleControlInterface.PrintArray` here. In this case, casting `(IConsoleControlInterface)arrayToBeSorted2` will show you the method `PrintArray` as you expect.

Unless you have specific reasons to explicitly implement an interface, [prefer implicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation) which would just be

`void PrintArray(int[] array) {...`

within `BubbleSortClass`. This will eliminate the need to cast the class to the appropriate interface in order to "see" the method.

Hope this helps!